# Misunderstanding with pointers

Tags: c++, c

I work with code that takes user-defined strings and prints them on a [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) monitor, using predefined font arrays saved in a header file. But there are lines of code that I couldn't understand in other source codes, like these ones:

```
uint8_t *rowoftext ; 
char *text[20] = {"string1","string2",.......,"srting20"};
```

What does this line really do?

```
rowoftext = (uint8_t *)text[textrow++];
```

How do I equalize an array of uint8_t pointers to another pointer?
Do I understand it well, or what does this line do?

Comment: `char "text[20]={"sting1","string2,.......,"srting19"};` does not even make sense: both logically and syntactically.

Comment: @Jefffrey Could be a typo and he meant `char *text[20]...`

Comment: even if it were a typo, he's assigning 19 elements to a 20 element array.

Comment: @nims Wrong fix. Please leave buggy code alone, it is the OP's responsibility to fix it.

Comment: @thang This is perfectly well-defined in C.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry, I thought the bug was added in revision 3 by raina77ow. My bad.

Comment: @DennisMeng, now it even makes less sense.

Comment: Nevermind, he finally fixed it for good. (Hopefully).

Comment: What a messy situation...

Answer (score 5):

The bit `(uint8_t *)` is called a *cast*. It converts one type to another, in this case one pointer type to another pointer type. This is very dangerous if the pointed-to objects aren't compatible, but in this case they are.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cast, consider the size of both data, before cast and after cast. If your size `before cast > after cast`, don't do it, because your data will be lost.

In your cast, calculate your before and after size.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be char *text[20] instead of char text[20]. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

Anyway, the above code is casting a character pointer to a uint8_t type pointer. It's better you avoid such casts. This works since both of them take only a byte. But, in general it's better to avoid them.

Comment: `char text[20]` is not what the OP wrote (although what the OP wrote does not make sense either).

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in gory detail:

```
uint8_t *rowoftext;
char *text[20] = {"string1","string2",.......,"srting20"};
```

- uint8_t is (probably) defined somewhere in a header file as:

  typdef unsigned char uint8_t;
- rowoftext is declared as a pointer, and defined with file scope as a pointer to uint8_t, and assigned a default value of NULL.
- text is declared as an array of pointers to signed char, and defined as an array of 20*sizeof(char*), either 80 on a 32bit system, or 160 on a 64bit system.

The line of code,

```
rowoftext = (uint8_t *)text[textrow++];
```

- determines the value of the variable textrow (probably defined as int or unsigned int
- increments the value stored in the textrow variable
- locates the textrow'th element of the array text and dereferences that address, equivalent to,

  *(text+textrow)
- this expression has type (char*), as text[] is of type (char*)
- coerces the pointer to char (char*) to another pointer type (uint8_t), which is unsigned
- the unchanged pointer is stored in the variable rowoftext

were you to look at rowoftext prior to this statement, it stored NULL or a previously assigned pointer value.  Now the variable rowoftext contains the pointer (address) which was stored in text[textrow].

The post-increment of textrow incremented the value of the variable textrow, but used the value of textrow prior to the increment.  This idiom is quite common in C and C++.

There is a difference between the following two declarations,

```
uint8_t *rowoftext;
uint8_t rowoftext[ integer_expression ];
```

The first declares rowoftext to be a variable that holds a pointer, which can be assigned the base address of an array, and then used to traverse an array, by incrementing the pointer.
The second declares a constant pointer to an array of uint8_t elements.  Both examples declare variables (sic) which can be used with the [] operator to address an array of uint8_t, like so,

```
rowoftext[ integer ]
```

which is equivalent to

```
*(rowoftext + integer)
```